# After Hours S&P 500

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, after-hours-trading

I know that while major stock markets are closed, many instruments continue trading overnight.  I imagine that some of these instruments track the S&P 500.  Is there some easy way to follow these?  I don't want to trade overnight, I just wish I could see how those markets move at any given time.

Comment: FWIW: If you do decide to do after hours trading then never sell at market. Always place a Limit Order.  Way back when I was interested in trading, I'd seen stocks sell for pennies that were worth $30-$40 dollars because there's sometimes not enough buyers at the stock's current price and the next bidder bid 10 cents.

Answer (score 3):

The futures market trades 24 hours a day, 5.5 days a week. S&P 500 futures market continues trading, and this gives pricing exposure and influences the individual stocks when they resume trading in US session.

Comment: How can a market trade 24 hours per day for five and one-half days a week? Thats only 5 x 24 and 1 x12 .

Comment: @Freiheit because it doesn't trade 24 hours on the half day? Don't worry about it that much, really not that complicated and nobody in this established market cares

Comment: In fact I tried to get some more clarity about the obnoxiously stated trading hours for the CME groups futures, in particular for the E-mini S&P 500, [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/141613/66803).

Answer (score 1):

## ::edit::

My original answer contained a fundamental error: it turns out that it is **not true** that any exchange can create its own product to track any underlying index.  If the underlying index is copyrighted (such as the S&P indices, Russell indices, Dow Jones indices, etc.) then the exchange must enter into a licensing agreement (usually exclusive) with the copyright holder in order to use the index's formula (and name).  Without such a license the exchange would only be able to **approximate** the underlying index, and I don't think that happens very much (because how would you market such a product?).

---

The [CME](http://www.cmegroup.com/) offers several futures (and other derivatives) whose face value is equivalent to some multiple of the S&P500's value *on the date when the product expires*.  When such a product is actively traded, it may serve as a reasonable indicator of the "market"'s expectation of the S&P500's *future* value.

So, you could pay attention to the [front month](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/front-month-contract.asp) of the [CME's S&P 500 Mini future](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500.html), which trades from 17:00-16:00 Chicago time, Sunday night through Friday afternoon.  But remember that the prices quoted there are

- an obscure multiple of the S&P 500's actual value (you need to read the documentation to learn what that multiple is, but if you only care about percent change then you might not care)
- what the market **expects** the S&P 500's value to be at expiration of the current contract (typically on the 15th of each month), meaning that on the 16th of any month that price may have very little to do with the **current** underlying index value

As another example, if you care about the Russell 2000 index, until 2017 the [ICE Exchange](https://www.theice.com/products/86) happened to hold the license for its derivatives.  They traded from 20:00-17:30 New York time, Sunday night through Friday afternoon.  But in mid-2017 CME bought that license as well, so now you'll want to track it [here](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-russell-2000.html).

Moral: There's almost always some "after hours" product out there tracking whatever index you care about, but you may have to do some digging to find it, and it might not be all that useful for your specific purpose.